# Formula to convert Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates?

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, real-numbers, spherical-coordinates

I have this formula:

```
x, y, z = cos(vertical)*sin(horizontal), sin(vertical), cos(vertical)*cos(horizontal)
```

Which maps a spherical coordinates (*horizontal* and *vertical*) to Cartesian coordinates (*x*, *y*, and *z*). What formula could I use to get the spherical coordinates back?

*EDIT: fixed formula error as noted by Paul Sinclair*

Comment: why aren't you using the standard spherical coordinate formulae for conversion?  $\rho^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$...etc.

Comment: @JHStrom - he is, except he wants a sphere itself, so $\rho = 1$, and he's twisted switched the coordinates around, and he's made an error in his formula.

Comment: The error I refer to is that by your formulas $x = z$, always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $x = \cos v\sin h, y = \sin v, z = \cos v\cos h$ (if you want the full words used, ask the programming exchanges instead of the math exchange - we hate typing)! Then consider what is $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$ and what is $\frac{x}{z}$. This should give you the answer.

(Edited to bring my equations in line with the correction to the OP.)

Comment: 1. Thanks for pointing out the error, but while I fixed it the formula is was a mixup of sin/cos in the z component, not what you posted. 2. Are you saying the formula is *v=sqrt(xx+zz) h=z/x* or did I misinterpret something?

Comment: No. what you are missing is that I did not give you the complete answer, but merely pointed in its direction. Perform the two calculations I indicate. Simplify the result (I assume you know how all your trig functions). That will allow *you* to figure out what functions you need.